# Creating a ndpanel in pandas (for n>5)

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python programming. I am working on a project that involves creating a 7 dimensional data variable for which I am trying to use a 7 D Panel created from ndpanel_factory in pandas.

There is not much document available online for working with ndpanel object (I understand it's experimental but if they have released it I think it must have the basic functionality)

I have a few queries:
    1. What is the importance of a slicer? I have successfully created a 7dpanel class by first creating a 5dpanel and 6dpanel with each being slicer of the before one. Is this hierarchy necessary or me being a novice is understanding it the wrong way?
    2. Which functions of DataFrame class are extensible to the ndpanel object? I have to store this variable (something similar to df_to_hdf) for future manipulation.

```
from pandas.core import panelnd
import pandas as pd
Panel5D = panelnd.create_nd_panel_factory(
    klass_name   = 'Panel5D',
    axis_orders  = [ 'cool', 'labels','items','major_axis','minor_axis'],
    axis_slices  = { 'labels' : 'labels', 'items' : 'items',
                 'major_axis' : 'major_axis', 'minor_axis' : 'minor_axis' },
    slicer  = pd.Panel4D,
    axis_aliases = { 'major' : 'major_axis', 'minor' : 'minor_axis' },
    stat_axis    = 2)
Panel6D = panelnd.create_nd_panel_factory(
    klass_name   = 'Panel6D',
    axis_orders  = [ 'xtracool', 'cool', 'labels','items','major_axis','minor_axis'],
    axis_slices  = { 'cool':'cool', 'labels' : 'labels', 'items' : 'items',
                 'major_axis' : 'major_axis', 'minor_axis' : 'minor_axis' },
    slicer  = Panel5D,
    axis_aliases = { 'major' : 'major_axis', 'minor' : 'minor_axis' },
    stat_axis    = 2)
Panel7D = panelnd.create_nd_panel_factory(
    klass_name   = 'Panel7D',
    axis_orders  = [ 'superxtracool', 'xtracool', 'cool', 'labels','items','major_axis','minor_axis'],
    axis_slices  = { 'xtracool':'xtracool', 'cool':'cool', 'labels' : 'labels', 'items' : 'items',
                 'major_axis' : 'major_axis', 'minor_axis' : 'minor_axis' },
    slicer  = Panel6D,
    axis_aliases = { 'major' : 'major_axis', 'minor' : 'minor_axis' },
    stat_axis    = 2)
    p7d = Panel7D(random.randn(2, 5, 3, 2, 10, 4, 7))
```

#### My project

I am trying to optimize variables for a specific sequence of algorithms by using something similar to grid search but the variables I need to optimize are in different scripts. Moreover the objective function cannot be described easily. Therefore I am manually building a 7D object with the data which I intend to store and plot with respect to different variables. Honestly, the number of values I have to look at are less So I do not want to get into any signal processing/machine learning.

Comment: you can look at this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748598/why-my-panelnd-factory-throwing-a-keyerror). Do you actually have 7-dimensional data? Working with something like this is pretty unweildy. Much better to break it up into smaller problems. A multi-level index is much better supported and usually much more useful.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff for the suggestion. No, my data is not 7-Dimesional per se but I am doing it for the convenience of analysis as I felt it might be natural for indexing purposes. Sorry I am new to python and database (I am an electrical engineer), can you please elaborate on multi-level indexing?

Comment: @Jeff I think you meant this: [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex)

Comment: yes...you can look at at that as well. Try a multi-index frame first, start simple.