# Is there any 'natural' way to order items, major_axis and minor_axis in Pandas Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple EEG (electroencephalography) datasets. When I have a single trial I organize each vectorial sample in time across electrodes as a row in a Python Pandas DataFrame and the signal through time in an electrode in a DataFrame column. This fits nicely with the way most/many people organize a data matrix with samples in rows and features in columns.

When I have multiple so-called 'trials' (where each trial is a DataFrame-like recording taken a different points) I organize the data in a Pandas Panel. The Panel uses, instead of the row/column terminology, 'items', 'major_axis', 'minor_axis' and I am wondering if there is any 'natural'/'canonical' way to order data in the Pandas Panel, - or if this is an entirely pedantic question?

I note that the Pandas book presents an example with stock values across multiple companies with time in the major axis, open/close/etc in the minor axis and stock symbol in the items. These data do not map well to my situation.

Initially I had trials as items, electrodes as major_axis and timepoints as minor_axis, but if I then take out a single trial by `data[1, :, :]` I end up with a DataFrame that is transposed in comparison with the ordinary data matrix ordering. Another stackoverflow user seems to have used this ordering: [Why my PanelND factory throwing a KeyError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748598/why-my-panelnd-factory-throwing-a-keyerror) and I suppose one can just use `data[1, :, :].T` to get a 'natural' ordering.

A (electrode x time x trial)-ordering gives a "nice" indexing with `data[:, :, 1]` returning an appropriately ordered DataFrame of size (time x electrode)

A (electrode x trial x time)-ordering also give a nice indexing with `data[:, 1, :]`, and furthermore `data.to_frame()` returns a very sensible DataFrame with hierarchical row indices with trials as major axis and time as minor.

I suppose the question of ordering is also dependent on the internal ordering of the Panel in relation to cache. In most cases the operations are across time.

What also bothers me is the different indexing in numpy.array and pandas.Panel:

```
>>> data[:, :, 1].shape
(6, 2500)
>>> data.values[:, :, 1].shape
(2500, 6)
```

Numpy's model seems more sensible.

**Update**

```
>>> n_times, n_electrodes, n_trials = 2500, 6, 10
>>> electrodes = ['C3', 'CZ', 'C4', 'P3', 'PZ', 'P4']
```

DataFrame:

```
>>> in_data = np.random.rand(n_times, n_electrodes)
>>> data = pd.DataFrame(in_data, columns=electrodes)
>>> data.C3                # Works fine
>>> data.ix[1000, 'C3']    # Works fine
```

Panel:

```
>>> in_data = np.random.rand(n_times, n_electrodes, n_trials)
>>> data = pd.Panel(in_data, major_axis=electrodes)
>>> data.C3           # Exception, would like to have.
>>> data[:, :, 9]     # Would like to have (2500, 6) here
```

Another attempt:

```
>>> data = pd.Panel(np.transpose(in_data, (1, 2, 0)), items=electrodes)
>>> data.C3      # Possible, but would like to have the DataFrame transposed.
>>> data[:, 9, :]      # Fine 
>>> data.to_frame()    # Fine
```

Regarding the first index as the 'row' index with time:

```
>>> data[2000, :, :]   # Completely wrong
```

Ideally:

```
>>> data = pd.Panel(in_data, columns=electrodes)
>>> data.C3            # returns (2500, 10) DataFrame
>>> data[:, :, 9]      # returns (2500, 6) DataFrame
>>> data[1000, :, :]   # returns (6, 10) DataFrame
>>> data.to_frame()    # returns (25000, 6) DataFrame
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  Are you saying you want to use, e.g., `electrodes` as the major_axis but index into it in a different way than what pandas gives you?  Can you show an example of what you currently are doing, what you get, and what you want to do/get instead?

Comment: With a Panel 'data' sized (items=2500, major=6, minor=10) = (time, electrodes, trials) I can do `data.values[:, :, 9]` and get a (2500, 6) array, while `data[:, :, 9]` gives me an "unnaturally transposed" (6, 2500). An ordering of (2500, 6) returned from Pandas would have made more sense to me. Other permutations of the items, major and minor axes neither seem give me a good intuitive indexing and returned DataFrame.

Comment: Again, please edit your question to include that information.  Instead of "a good intuitive indexing and returned DataFrame", please show code examples (maybe hypothetical ones) showing specifically what index values you want to pass and what data/shapes you expect to get out.

Comment: I think there are two separate issues here:  (1) how is the data stored (3x4 vs 4x3), and (2) what do you want to do with the data?  For the most part, if you are working in pandas, #1 is irrelevant b/c pandas does all the alignment for you.  If you are doing stuff in numpy, then yeah, it matters b/c you do the alignment yourself.  So maybe you want to ask a question more along the line of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that pandas is organized differently than numpy here because columns can be of different types (int/float/object), hence necessitating a column-style organization of numpy arrays.

Comment: I am not sure I understand why Pandas should be organized differently than Numpy because of different types. `pd.DataFrame([[3, 'yes'], [2, 'no']], columns=['C3', 'label'])` works as well as the transposed version: `pd.DataFrame([[3, 'yes'], [2, 'no']], columns=['C3', 'label']).T`.

Comment: Perhaps we should think of 'minor_axis' as the column-like dimension that could potentially have different types, while 'major_axis' is the row and 'items' is the auxilliary? That makes sense in terms of the Pandas book example where the minor axis contains price and volume, ie, different types.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a pandas developer and not at all qualified to give you the ins and outs of why you have c-contiguous here and f-contigous there.  I don't know what to say except that if you want full control over that sort of thing, you probably want to use numpy.  The whole point of pandas (in a sense) is to NOT not to have to worry about that sort of thing.

Comment: You could also consider doing things with MultiIndex or groupby instead of panel, btw.  I know some folks like panel but generally speaking I'd rather stick to 2 dimensions for most data.  Not sure if that helps you at all, but something you could consider.